# How to make optional parameters in body with Restler 3?

Tags: php, restler

I want some parameters to be optional in the JSON body. I have made phpdocs and set the parameter to null:

```
/**
 * Create a new text
 *
 * @param int $product_id       product id
 * @param int $template_id      {@from body} template id
 * @param string $language      {@from body} the language of the text
 * @param string $name          {@from body} product name
 *
 * @url POST {product_id}/texts
 */
public function postText($product_id, $template_id, $market_id = null)
{ }
```

But Restler gives me:

```
{
   "error": {
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Bad Request: market_id is missing."
   }
}
```

How do I specify a parameter to be optional?

Answer (score 2):

Got it. My code wasn't complete, I actually had multiple parameters like:

```
function($a, $b = null, $c, $d = 5)
```

The problem was that `$b` was required although I had set a value to it. The problem is solved by putting all optional parameters last, like so:

```
function($a, $c, $b = null, $d = 5)
```